# Can't get radiobuttons to email with php/js

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, contacts

Im trying to make the "geef een cijfer van 1 t/m 10" into radio buttons so that the user can click on a value from 1 to 10 and then the result gets emailed to us. I can't get this to work for some reason though.

I was wondering if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
   var cijfer = $("input#cijfer").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
   var work_abroad = $("input#work_abroad").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
     cijfer: cijfer,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Uw deelname is verzonden. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

```css
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message'])     ||
    empty($_POST['cijfer'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }
 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = $_POST['cijfer'];
 
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'donny@zenze.eu'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Klanttevredenheid onderzoek:  $name";
$email_body = "U heeft een waardering ontvangen via de landingspagina.\n\n"."Hier zijn de gegevens:\n\nNaam: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nBedrijf: $phone\n\nCijfer: $message\n\nMotivatie:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@canconnect.nl\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;   
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>CanConnect - Graag uw mening</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/kerstkaart.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
 <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
   <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/cct.png" alt="" style="margin-top:10px;">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
      
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
   
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
        <div class="container">

       

        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
         <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Enquête</h2>
                    <hr class="star-primary">
                </div>
            </div>         

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <!-- To configure the contact form email address, go to mail/contact_me.php and update the email address in the PHP file on line 19. -->
                    <!-- The form should work on most web servers, but if the form is not working you may need to configure your web server differently. -->
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Bedrijfsnaam</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Uw bedrijfsnaam" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Vul uw bedrijfsnaam in.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Naam</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Uw naam" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Vul uw naam in">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>E-mailadres</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Uw emailadres" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Vul uw emailadres in.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                         <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Uw waardering voor CanConnect</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Geef een cijfer van 1 t/m 10" id="cijfer" required data-validation-required-message="Graag uw cijfer">
                                <input type="radio" id="work_abroad" name="work_abroad" value="y" /><label for="work_abroad_y">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="work_abroad" name="work_abroad" value="n" /><label for="work_abroad_n">No</label>
                                                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Uw motivatie</label>
                                <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Uw motivatie" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Voer een bericht in"></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">verstuur</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    
                                        
                    </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>           

            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">

                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                               
    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
     <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section class="success" id="informatie">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Geachte gebruiker van CanConnect,</h2>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <p>Op deze pagina kunt u ons laten weten welk rapportcijfer u geeft voor de totale performance van CanConnect. </br> </br> Naast het rapportcijfer kunt u ook in eigen woorden laten weten wat u van ons vind. Gebruik hiervoor het onderste veld bij motivatie.
Uw mening is voor ons erg belangrijk en stelt ons in staat onze dienstverlening en producten te verbeteren.
</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p> Zodat onze dienstverlening bijdraagt aan het succes van uw bedrijf.

</br></br>Alvast bedankt voor uw vriendelijke medewerking,</br></br>

Ivo van Herwaarde</br>
<i>CanConnect</i></br> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <a href="http://www.canconnect.nl" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                        <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Naar onze website
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                     Copyright &copy; <a href="http://www.canconnect.nl">Canconnect</a> | Website by <a href="http://www.zenze.nl">Zenze</a>    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>
    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `<input type="text">` rather than `<input type="radio">`

Just use the same name for each radio button.
You can try it out here http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_radio

Or more fitting to your needs would be a `<input type="range">` in my opinion
http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_range

Comment: My bad, I uploaded an older version. I already did this. It still won't show up in the test mails I'm sending though. Any ideas? I updated the HTML, JS and php I uploaded earlier too.

Comment: You've tried to switch it to radio but you dont get the data on the server side?

Try dumping all the $_POST data and look for it there. var_dump($_POST);

If it dosent exist in the $_POST variable, you're not sending it correctly with the Ajax submit.

Comment: This is my first time php to be honest. Where do my "dump" results show and where should I put it in the code?

Comment: You could use the debugging tool in your browser. First off, in the PHP file, just write var_dump($_POST); die();

Then bring up the debugging tool (f12) and go to the network tab. Then submit the form and go back to the debugging tool, and press the new post entry that will show. Go to Preview or response on that entry and you will see the output.

Comment: It doesnt matter where you put it, but do it just after the `<?php` tag